# Parameter with '&' breaking $.ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameter-passing

I'm developing a Web App that uses JavaScript + JQuery on the client side and PHP on the server side.

One of the strings I want to pass as parameter for an AJAX Request has a '&' in its content.

For this reason, the string of the request is broken. The browser "thinks" that this parameters is over because there is a '&' on the string.

```
var hasChar = "This is a string that has a & in the content.";
var doesntHave = "This one does not contain.";
var dataString = "first=" + hasChar + "&second=" + doesntHave;

$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "myurl.php",
    data : dataString,
    cache : false,
    success : function(html) {
    }
});
```

The server receives the first parameter as "This is a string that has a "

My Question:

How to I encode the string on the client side and how should I decode it on the PHP server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not to do following:

```
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "myurl.php",
        data : {
          'first': hasChar,
          'second': doesntHave
        },
        cache : false,
        success : function(html) {
        }
    });
```

In this case jQuery will make sure that string is properly encoded.

As an alternative you can use encodeURIComponent() JS's built in function for properly encoding strings:

```
var dataString = "first=" + encodeURIComponent(hasChar) + "&second=" + encodeURIComponent(doesntHave);
```

Answer (score 8):

Let jQuery handle the encoding of `hasChar` (and your other params) for you:

```
var hasChar = "This is a string that has a & in the content.";
var doesntHave = "This one does not contain.";

$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "myurl.php",
    data : { first: hasChar, second: doesntHave },
    cache : false,
    success : function(html) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/);

```
dataString = $.param({first: asChar, second: doesntHave});
```

Answer (score 1):

or if you want to skip the `$.param` part as metioned by @alex-k

```
data : {'first': hasChar, 'second': doesntHave},
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just set it as an object:

```
var hasChar = "This is a string that has a & in the content.";
var doesntHave = "This one does not contain.";

$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "myurl.php",
    data : {first: hasChar, second: doesntHave},
    cache : false,
    success : function(html) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `encodeURI`:

```
var encodedData = encodeURI(dataString);
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "myurl.php",
    data : encodedData,
    cache : false,
    success : function(html) {
    }
});
```

[Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)

Answer (score 0):

If you want server-side de/encoding use `urlencode()` and `urldecode()`.

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question.

Comment: @bazmegakapa: It was - the question was edited. "How to I encode the string on the _server_ side..." was the original question.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
var dataString = {};
dataString["hasChar"] = "This is a string that has a & in the content.";
dataString["doesntHave"] = "This one does not contain.";

$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "myurl.php",
    data : dataString,
    cache : false,
    success : function(html) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters need to be simply URL-encoded. On the PHP side, you won't need to decode them, everything will work as normal.

There is a Javascript function called [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) that will correctly URL-encode your string. So on the basic level, you can do this:

```
var dataString = "first=" + encodeURIComponent(hasChar) + "&second=" + encodeURIComponent(doesntHave);
```

If you use jQuery, it will automatically handle this for you, if [in your $.ajax() call you pass it an object instead of a query string](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#sending-data-to-server):

> The data option can contain either a query string of the form
>   key1=value1&key2=value2, or a map of the form {key1: 'value1', key2:
>   'value2'}. If the latter form is used, the data is converted into a
>   query string using jQuery.param() before it is sent.

So you only have to do this in your code:

```
var dataString = { first: hasChar, second: doesntHave);
```