# Parameter with '&' breaks AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, ajax

Though this is pretty much a duplicate of this question:  [Parameter with '&' breaking $.ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184438/parameter-with-breaking-ajax-request), the answers given there are not the ones that help me to solve my problem. The reason is, both the question and the answers are jQuery (which I don't understand).

I need to send an Ajax call with a string parameter that sometimes contains a '&' like in "RGR Kabel GmbH & Co. KG".

For example, I have this AJAX-function (simplified):

```
function getData()
{
    var param = "RGR Kabel GmbH & Co. KG";
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200)
        {
        [... do something]
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "../getData.php?q1="+param, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The '&' in the `param` variable breaks the AJAX Call. Instead of one parameter:

```
q1 : "RGR Kabel GmbH & Co. KG"
```

There are recognized two parameters:

```
q1 : "RGR Kabel GmbH "
Co. KG :
```

Is there any possibility to prevent the AJAX call from breaking when using '&' inside the parameter?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `&` serves the purpose of separating querystring parameters within a URI, if you want to send data containing that character, you will have to encode all data before adding it to the URI. You can use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) for that purpose.

Like this in your case:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "../getData.php?q1="+encodeURIComponent(param), true);
```

Comment: Thanks, with this solution the ajax call is working. But: now the php script breaks because the parameter is received as "RGR Kabel GmbH &amp; Co. KG". What is the correct way to convert this string back to what it was ("RGR Kabel GmbH & Co. KG"). Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Jbartmann That depends on what server language you are using. For PHP it would be [`urldecode()`](http://se1.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) for .Net you could use [`HttpUtility.UrlDecode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy.aspx). Other languages will have similar methods. "URL decode" is the word your looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I am using PHP and it works perfectly.