# TinyMce mysql issue with special characters

Tags: mysql, tinymce

I'm having an issue where i have Tinymce editor saving HTML to the database.

Apparently when ever i have something like a   in the middle of the text, when i hit save, it saves everything before the   and anything after the   gets discarded, or any special character that will have a ASCII code like the above... I believe what is braking is the &.

do you guys have any ideas how to solve this issue?

cheers
dan

Comment: may be this link help: http://community.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=640

Comment: thats a different issue :(

Comment: i do not know what you are talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok turns out that was my Ajax code that was causing issues and the answer is here:

[Parameter with '&' breaking $.ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184438/parameter-with-breaking-ajax-request)